# How to use type predicates when using Array.filter with arrow function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have problem with using type predicates with arrow function.

```
// this working good 
function filterUndefined1<T>(x: T | undefined): x is T {
  return !x;
}
[1, undefined, 3, 5, undefined].filter(filterUndefined1);


// Retrun Type Error
type FilterUndefined2 = <T>(x: T | undefined) => x is T;
const filterUndefined2: FilterUndefined2 = (x: string) => !x;

// What I want to do
[1, undefined, 3, 5, undefined].filter(filterUndefined2);

// this working good
[1, undefined, 3, 5].filter(<T>(z: T | undefined): z is T => !z);
```

Why does my arrow function cause a type error when it leaves the filter argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `is T` assertions are lying, the code ensures that the values are falsy instead.

To fix the `filterUndefined2` declaration the corresponding type's generic parameter should be moved and the argument has to match the type; `string` does not match `T | undefined`.

```
type FilterUndefined2<T> = (x: T | undefined) => x is undefined;
const filterUndefined2: FilterUndefined2<string> =
    (x: string | undefined): x is undefined => !x;
```

This is still wrong for the usage with the example array, though, because that does not contain strings. Hence, this would work:

```
type FilterUndefined2<T> = (x: T | undefined) => x is undefined;
const filterUndefined2: FilterUndefined2<number> =
    (x: number | undefined): x is undefined => !x;
console.log([1, undefined, 3, 5, undefined].filter(filterUndefined2));
```

If you actually want to keep the values, which would make more sense, you can invert again using `!` or just do something like `x != null`.

```
type FilterUndefined2<T> = (x: T | undefined) => x is T;
const filterUndefined2: FilterUndefined2<number> =
    (x: number | undefined): x is number => !!x;
console.log([1, undefined, 3, 5, undefined].filter(filterUndefined2));
```